# How do I read the first element in an array when the array is a property of an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm using IGDB's API to get a release date for each game that is found from a search, but most games have numerous release dates, so those are all stored in an array, and that array is an object property. When I make a general API request, here is how the data is formatted:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5440,
        "name": "Kirby Triple Deluxe",
        "release_dates": [
            {
                "id": 16596,
                "human": "Jan 11, 2014"
            },
            {
                "id": 16598,
                "human": "May 16, 2014"
            },
            {
                "id": 250078,
                "human": "May 01, 2014"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the code I used to log the entire release_dates array:

```
const collections = response.data;
collections.forEach(collection => {
  console.log(collection.name);
  console.log(collection.release_dates);
});
```

How can I read just the first element in the array? I want to view the "human" property of the first element. One thing I tried was `collection.release_dates[0].human` but that did not work.

EDIT: To give a bit more clarity: the error I get when I try `console.log(collection.release_dates[0].human);` within the forEach loop is this: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

Comment: Why collection.release_dates[0].human didn't work. Did it throw an error?

Comment: Make sure you use `collection.release_dates[0].human` inside the `forEach` loop. It should work, and the output should be `Jan 11, 2014`

Comment: Before we get any more answers with `collection[0]`, could you please confirm the **exact** data structure of `response.data`. Is it the JSON snippet in your question or is that representing something else? Use `console.log("response.data:", JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))` and [edit] your question with the result

Comment: collections.forEach(collection =>{
    console.log(collection['release_dates'][0]['human'])
}
            )

Comment: @SarthakGupta I fail to see how that would make any difference at all

Comment: when foreach maybe there are elements with release dates has 0 elements so [0].human errors? in that case use optional chaining ?.[0]?.human

Comment: I get this error when I try that code within the forEach: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')```

Comment: Sounds like @cmgchess got it right then. You have records without a `release_dates` property. Some simple debugging would have gone a long way

Comment: @Sami you should validate if the `release_dates` have array length > 0 first with `if(collection.release_dates.length)`.

Comment: @Jordy that will suffer from the exact same issue (read the error message again)

Comment: @Jordy Yep, that did the trick. Some results do not have a release date, which seems to be causing the crash. I limited the search to only pull up one result that I knew had a release date and it worked. Question is, how can I make my code ignore the release date if there are no release dates on the list? I tried something already but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on others answers, here is one where you can also rely on fallback.

```js
collections.forEach(collection => {
  const releaseDate = collection?.release_dates?.[0]?.human ?? 'No release date.'
});
```

`??` is called [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). Even if `release_dates[0]` could be `undefined`, you can reliably fallback on "No release date." string.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases if `release_dates` key is not present in the object, it will throw `undefined` error. So, you should use optional chaining.

```js
collection.release_dates?.[0]?.human
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your object is part of a top-level array itself...

i guess you referred to that array as "collection", didnt you?

if that array (that contains your object) is referenced under "collection" you should be able to acces it with

```
collection[0]["release_dates"][0]
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: this did not work

Answer (score -2):

I wonder why this didn't work according to the asker.

```js
let collections = [
    {
        "id": 5440,
        "name": "Kirby Triple Deluxe",
        "release_dates": [
            {
                "id": 16596,
                "human": "Jan 11, 2014"
            },
            {
                "id": 16598,
                "human": "May 16, 2014"
            },
            {
                "id": 250078,
                "human": "May 01, 2014"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5441,
        "name": "Kirby Triple Deluxe 2",
        "release_dates": []
    }
];
collections.forEach(collection => {
  if(collection.release_dates.length) {
    console.log(collection.release_dates[0].human);
  }
});
```

Comment: OP already said that didn't work

Comment: Probably, the response shared by OP is not complete. If it was, then this code would have worked.

Comment: I didn't manually make the collections object. That is a list I get from IGDB's API whenever a user makes a search. I'll include the full code in the OP to add more clarity

Comment: Please share full of data for finding bugs